# Cloud Database for Java Application using Netbeans

Tags: java, parse-platform, netbeans-7

Is there any free cloud database that can be used for desktop application designed in JAVA using Netbeans ?
I am familiar with parse. But they does'nt provide about support for JAVA applications.
Came across Almonds API for Parse. But I cant understand how to use it with the netbeans project.
Kindly help me out !
Thanks in advance !! :)

Comment: Is this a project written in Netbeans? In which case Netbeans is really somewhat irrelevant here. Or is this a project written on the Netbeans RCP platform?

Comment: No my question is I need a cloud database which can be used with a Swing based Java application..